# What's the proper way to check if an element has an ID or not with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought I could check if an element has an ID with `has()` like this:

```
if ($button.has('#Menu-Icon')[0] !== undefined) {
   //do stuff
}
```

but I learned that instead, it checks if there's a descendant which matches the ID. So I don't think this is the right jQuery method to use, but nevertheless it's the only thing that seems to show up when I search the subject on Google.

**Which jQuery method is the right one for checking if a given element has a certain ID or not?**

Answer (score 5):

Check the id using the `attr()` function like this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'TheID') {
    alert('The button you pressed has the id: "TheID"!');
  } else {
    alert('You pressed a button with another id..');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="TheID">TheID</button>
<button id="anotherID">anotherID</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the id property like of the underlying element like

```
if ($button[0].id == 'Menu-Icon') {
   //do stuff
}
```

or jQuery way to use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```
if ($button.is('#Menu-Icon')) {
   //do stuff
}
```

The [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) method is used to filter a set of elements by checking whether those contains elements matching the passed selector, also it returns a jQuery object so checking for `undefined` will never be true

Comment: Thanks! Is there any difference at all between those two methods, performance or functionality wise?

Comment: `$button[0].id` will be faster... but might cause error if `$button[0]` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below which should work:

```
<div id=""></div> 

 $(document).ready(function(){
       if($('div').attr('id') != ''){
           alert("have id");   
       }else{
            alert("do not have id")   
       }
    });
```

Comment: try in this way, may it ll help.